# Migrating SQL server, concern about servername

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm getting ready to migrate from SQL Server 2005 onto a new server with SQL Server 2012, and a question was brought up this morning (and the migration is tomorrow of course).
The old server was called XYZ and the DB had the same name. So, in connection strings we were just using XYZ to connect.
On the new server, I also named the DB XYZ, but to connect I use NewServer/XYZ.
The plan is that tmrw when we go live with the new DB to rename the server XYZ and give it the old servers IP address so that everything that connects to it will run, business as usual.
The concern from one of the sysops is that once we change the servername we'll need to use XYZ/XYZ to connect to the new server.
I was hoping that someone could point me towards how to test for this before going live? Having to change all the connections would be a big job and include a lot of downtime.

Comment: Your question belongs on dba.stackexchange.com, but even then it's unclear as written. Is XYZ a server name, an instance name or a database name? You could use the same for all three (`Server Name=XYZ\XYZ;Database=XYZ`), but that's probably not what's going on here. Use unambiguous terms.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the instance name (the bit after the \ ).
So you'll need to connect using XYZ\XYZ.

Comment: I eventually did fix the issue. Can't remember the exact details, but in one of the config files I pointed the DB to the loopback IP. Then I was able to connect without the \. If anyone has questions about this was done, I might be able to dig it up. Thank goodness for consultants!